# Weird bahaviour of countif/vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

I have a sheet containing allotments and who the plot holder is. All plot holders pay a subscription each year. If they have 2 plots the sheet skips the 2nd and further plots, they only pay once.

I have added a column called 'Insurance' and the code was copied across from column R to column Q, simple.

However, there is a rogue line with '44' as the member's number (Row 49). He has 2 plots so it should list his subscription once and no more. However, it is not listing his first occurence with the subscription, it is blank and so is the 2nd occurence. Tried evrything, even changing his membership number - and it worked. I have formatted the cell, cleared contents etc etc. but it will not work with the 44 as a subscription. 
I am using the following code:

```
=IF($F49<>"",IF(COUNTIF($F:$F,$F49&"")>1,IF(COUNTIF($F$4:G49,$F49&"")=1,IFERROR(VLOOKUP("I",TariffLookup,5,FALSE),$M49),""),IFERROR(VLOOKUP("I",TariffLookup,5,FALSE),$M49)),0)
```

It is interesting that the 2nd countif gives a figure of 8 just for the one row, the rest of the sheet it gives 0, 1 or 2 - no member has more that 2 plots. There are 178 rows in the sheet, I have tried to reproduce the error elsewhere but to no avail. I entered another row with 44 and it correctly fills with blanks. I put a 44 before row 49, the same happens. I have deleted the 2nd 44, it works perfectly. Wherever I put the 2nd 44 it doesn't work on the first occurrence.

Help...

Comment: I have solved the immediate problem by adding an 'a' so both occurences become 44a and it works ok. But I still have the underlying problem, why only the number 44?

Comment: without any screenshot , sample file/data.. we (the one whom tried to solve this..) can just assume a lot of things..(including 'TariffLookup' column/values..) | imho.. there is something to do with the logic.. | Try to break down the combined if and see which of the 5 IF in the statements 'kicks' the expected/unexpected value/outcome... | If it was me.. I'll do it this way (to trace the root of the problem..)

Comment: I can only saperate the code as https://pastebin.com/2V1hq8Qi ... but couldn't proceed to test/check further.. -_-"